# Intel OpenVINO memory leaks with VS2017

Tags: c++, intel, openvino

I am using `OpenVINO 2020.3.194`, with `Windows10 x64` and `VS2017`.
I can run the Intel `C++` examples, but when I use the inference in my application, I got lots of memory leaks at the exit. Here are some of them:

```
{2395} normal block at 0x00000260E6A3BCF0, 48 bytes long.
 Data: <google.protobuf.> 67 6F 6F 67 6C 65 2E 70 72 6F 74 6F 62 75 66 2E 
{2394} normal block at 0x00000260E5958350, 16 bytes long.
 Data: <    `           > 20 01 A4 E6 60 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
{2393} normal block at 0x00000260E6A40100, 88 bytes long.
 Data: <    `       `   > B0 E4 A2 E6 60 02 00 00 10 E4 A2 E6 60 02 00 00 
{2388} normal block at 0x00000260E6A41FB0, 32 bytes long.
 Data: <google.protobuf.> 67 6F 6F 67 6C 65 2E 70 72 6F 74 6F 62 75 66 2E 
{2387} normal block at 0x00000260E5958170, 16 bytes long.
 Data: <    `           > 80 00 A4 E6 60 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
{2386} normal block at 0x00000260E6A40060, 88 bytes long.
 Data: < w  `       `   > A0 77 BC E5 60 02 00 00 20 09 A4 E6 60 02 00 00 
{2381} normal block at 0x00000260E6A3BC80, 48 bytes long.
 Data: <google.protobuf.> 67 6F 6F 67 6C 65 2E 70 72 6F 74 6F 62 75 66 2E
```

I suspect that happens because I am using Unicode characters set and shared MFC DLL, while the examples compile with MBCS. How I can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try running inference using OpenVINO 2020.4.
Do let us know if this works for you.